# Random Forest regression: Input variables most likely to maximize output variable

Tags: random-forest, optimization

I have a large number of observations of the form:

i1, i2...in -> output

I "trained" a random forest using two thirds of the data and verified the predictions made using the random forest on the last third.

The "fit" is good and the predictions are of very high quality.

Now, I would like to figure out which arrangement of input variables **tends to** maximize the output variable.

I know random forests never yield output values that exceed the maximum output value found in the training dataset.

I also realize random forests are not designed for that type of work, but I can imagine a dominant arrangement of input variables that is most likely to approach the maximum value.

All input variables are continuous in this case.

Any ideas?

Based on the feedback below, here is a data sample:

`99.5980361  100.1584786 100.1582278 100.1579779 100 100.3943218 100.3142184 98.59044636 100.5968869 99.36127373
100.1594392 99.75728155 99.43227899 100.4893964 99.51298701 100.6525285 100.3241491 100.8077544 98.74569242 99.34908777
100.0746469 99.66352624 99.79743417 100.67659   99.59677419 100 99.52766532 101.3559322 101.1724732 99.33385205`

The last number is the result variable. I sorted the observations in descending order by the result variable values.

Let's say I take all observations for which the result variable value is greater than 99.5 and then average average the values of all predictor variable values for those observations. Would the resulting array of averaged predictor variable values correspond to the arrangement of predictor variables most likely to maximize the output variable?

Comment: You could explore individual input variables by looping over all variables used to build your model, assigning a mean value to all but one input variable and checking a scatterplot of the one input and output. You can find these plots quite interesting and some of them will clearly show how input affects the output.

Comment: Another option is to use (possibly) built in function of input-output dependency. I used this function is R's GBM, which produced heat map of the dependency.

Comment: I thought about it some more and I wonder: Would the result differ significantly if took all observations for which the output value belongs to the top percentile and average them? I guess there could be a better solution not present in the given observations. But how much better would it be?

Comment: I am not following. Could you present an idea in the original question with some supplementary data?

Comment: I added some info, but I think I lack the domain-specific vocabulary to express myself correctly or accurately.

Comment: **Would the resulting array of averaged predictor variable values correspond to the arrangement of predictor variables most likely to maximize the output variable?** Do you want to average each predictor separately, or average all predictors with respect to separate observations?

Comment: If I understand correctly you are trying to come up with a *linear* relationship between your predictors and dependent. I don't think the decisions trees can do that. You can try fitting a linear model in addition, that should give an explicit weight to each variable that gives you information about its contribution to the value of the dependent. Doing this _conditional_ on the dependent value (i.e. which features contribute most for y>100) is a different question. You could fit different linear models for each range of y you are interested in.

Comment: @AlexeyBurnakov I thought about averaging each predictor separately. In the scenario I described, I imagined that if I select the top 5% of all observations ranked by output value in descending order, then those 5% must have predictor values that "surround" the optimal arrangement of predictor values.

Comment: I understand you. This may help you, but it is not a reliable method I think. The issues is that your predictors can have non linear relationship with output, and their averaged values for top-0.05 outputs are not necessarily different from the average for bottom-0.05, or mid-0.5. You cannot see analyze this. That is why analyzing full predictor support with conjuction to the output is a broader and more informative way.

Comment: @L_R_T, you may want to check out this recent paper for some relevant thoughts: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.10883.pdf

Comment: @Ariel Great paper. It will take some time to digest.